# Android Package structure

Tags: android

My default package name is `com.xont.controller` (R file contain that package.Eclipse generated one) . I want to make it more packages.Like 'com.xont.controller.sales`and 'com.xont.controller.admin` like this: And I added activity also in manifestfile

**Edited**

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.android.xont.controller"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:label="Xont" android:icon="@drawable/virtusel64">

    <activity android:name=".AndroidAppXontActivity"
              android:label="Xont">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" 
             android:label="Login">
    </activity>


 <activity android:name=".syn.DatabaseCheckActivity" 
             android:label="Databse Setup">
  </activity>
   ...........
```

Package structure is:
  [image]

Error says : **android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.xont.controller/com.xont.controller.syn.DatabaseSetupActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?**

Please help me what i want to do here.

Comment: can you show manifest entry for the activity...

Comment: I updated That manifest file content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All components that are registered as `.SomeName` use manifest's `package` value as prefix. So basicaly you regsitered activity `.AndroidAppXontActivity` as `com.android.xont.controller.AndroidAppXontActivity`. But there is no such java class.

You should fix your component names to have full name to your Java class, like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.xont.controller.AndroidAppXontActivity" ... />
```

Same for all other components.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
<activity android:name="com.xont.controller.syn.DatabaseSetupActivity" 
             android:label="Databse Setup">
</activity>
```